# How to Pass Command Line Arguments to MSI Installer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-installer

Now my team working in a project using **Windows Application(C#)**. We use **MSI Installer** for creating installation.

I didn't know how to pass command line parameters from MSI file & Setup.exe file.

for example

setup.msi username=demo password=pass

setup.exe username=demo password=pass

Please suggest a good example/reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/command_lines_setups.aspx) Code Project article has a pretty good example of doing this.

Answer (score 10):

You've got the right idea, but for the parameters to be available during the execute sequence, you'll need to pass public properties rather than private ones.  Names of public properties are all uppercase.

For example, this would work:

```
msiexec /i setup.msi USERNAME=yourUserName PASSWORD=yourPassword
```

Answer (score 1):

Ed has it correct.

For "Setup.exe" installers - that is outside of the scope of MSI because setup.exe installers are proprietary to the vendors. InstallShield, Wise and WiX use different setup.exe cmdline params to acheive the same result.