# Msi insaller passing paramenter from command prompt for Set Service Login

Tags: windows-services, installation, windows-installer, command

**Installer builder tool**: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 , Project Installer

I am trying to pass username and password for the installer to use for running Windows services that will install by the installer. By default installer ask the Credentials during installation that i want to pass through command prompt. see attached pic [image: Set Service Login dialog during installation]
 I tried the solution that provided in the following issue. But still getting the "Set Service login" dialog during installation.

> msiexec /i setup.msi USERNAME=yourUserName PASSWORD=yourPassword

[How to Pass Command Line Arguments to MSI Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528363/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-msi-installer)

Comment: Any answer would depend on the tool you're using to build your installer.

Comment: Installer builder tool: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 , Project Installer

Comment: Why does your installer ask for credentials? Are you doing this from a custom action? If so, you need to modify that custom action. MSI packages don't prompt for service credentials by default

Answer (score 1):

Need to redesign Instalation using This http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16767/How-to-Pass-Command-Line-Arguments-to-MSI-Installe aticle

I use additional for installer class logic:

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Context.Parameters["password"]))
        {
            this.QualsMetricsSchedulerServiceInstaller.Password = this.Context.Parameters["password"];
            this.QualsMetricsSchedulerServiceInstaller.Username = this.Context.Parameters["user"];
        }
        else
        {
            this.Context.Parameters.Remove("user");
            this.Context.Parameters.Remove("password");
            this.QualsMetricsSchedulerServiceInstaller.Password = null;
            this.QualsMetricsSchedulerServiceInstaller.Username = null;
        }
        base.Install(stateSaver);
    }
```

And CustomActionData: /USERNAME="[USERNAME]" /PASSWORD="[PASSWORD]"
Now can install manualy and for silent instal use msiexec /i QualsScheduler.msi /qb username=.\Gavrishdv password=***