# Unattended Installation of an EXE (Without user interaction)

Tags: windows

Is there any scripting language available for creating Silent Installation (without giving input and clicking next, agree and finish)...? I want to do unattended installation of NewsGator.exe application in windows server, which scripting would be best..? Thanks in Advance for your reply.

Comment: Try adding an argument of `/y` to the command

Comment: That completely depends on what _exactly_ you're doing.

Comment: It should be a script which includes inputs that installation requires and when we run that, it should run the installation without asking for Click next and finish options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Pass Command Line Arguments to MSI Installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528363/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-msi-installer)

Comment: Can the Newsgator setup.exe be converted to msi..? If we do that, we need to find how to pass configuration inputs in unattended installation...

Answer (score 1):

[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) provides the very simple `/S` flag for running installers.
It's also extremely easy to create a dead simple installer.

Comment: What is dead simple installer..? will it be able to set configuration inputs when running unattended installation..?

Comment: Yes, you can set the install directory and change configuration files via the installer silently. Changing the config files does require a bit of work but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

All the MSI installers can support silent installations supplying the input parameters thru the command line in the form of:

installer.exe /v/qn"PARAMETER=VALUE PARAMETER=VALUE"

Comment: ok, Do you have any sample scripts that used to install unattended installation of any applications which is in the above format that you have given. Also, Can we pass Next, Agree and Finish operations through this parameters..?

Comment: In unattended installations all the input data is taken from the command line (or default values) and all the steps (Next, etc) are executed automatically. I'm sorry but here I don't have samples, you will find them easily on google.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not much familiar with these command line inputs and already tried to get these stuffs from Google, but couldn’t find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try autoit, here is an example of how to automate a WinZip install :

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/winzip/winzip.htm

I have used it to automate several installs in the company i work with, its pretty straight forward.

Comment: Yes it is very straight forward as you said. I'm under a little confusion about how we make all that commands to a single script file and how we have to give license key via script...?

Comment: did you take a look at the copmleted script provided by the [demo](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/winzip/script.txt)? You can just wait for the window that asks for the serial key and just type `Send("LICENCE_KEY")` and continue with the install.

Comment: Yes I had a look on it. Do we need hold all those commands to a single .bat file and run..?

Comment: nope, you input all those commands to the compiler for autoit and it will build an executable file, when you run the exe file it will run all those commands...if i have a chance today or tomorrow i will donwload the trial for newsgator and build the script and post it here....

Comment: Do we need to install any add-on's to operate these scripting commands in windows..? Were you able to get the script Ray..?

Comment: after you compile the script to an EXE file you dont need to install anything else on the clinet machine that will run it.